# Cómo puedo compilar con opción de lincado en un makefile?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo un inconveniente al hacer un Makefile.

Lo que sucede es que hice un Makefile para compilar los archivos.c y ejecutarlos, y todo funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, quiero agregarle la opción de compilarlo de tal forma que pueda luego hacer debug, y es aquí donde me surge una duda. la opción -g se hace en el compilado de cada archivo.c o es en el linkado?

Agradezco sus conocimientos para solucionar mi duda.

Acontinuación dejo el makefile que he hecho...

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

CHEADERS=./headers/
BUILD_DIR=build

CINCLUDES=-I$(CHEADERS)

PROJECT=ejecutable
OUTDEBUGGER=ejecutableDebug

SOURCES=main.c verificationDataIn.c converter.c
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(SOURCES:.c=.o))

VPATH=src

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDES) -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR) :
    mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)

clean:
    rm $(BUILD_DIR)/* >/dev/null 2>&1

runEjecutable:
    ./$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT)

debugEjecutable:
    gdb $(PROJECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

La opción -g se debe usar en la compilación de cada archivo para la generación de los archivos objeto (sufijo `-o`). La opción -g en el proceso de lincado no hará nada